# Displaying the result of an update based on a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to show the number of rows updated affected by the following code;

```
UPDATE [document]
SET CalculatedTime = CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, PrimaryDate) < 9 
                             THEN 'Pre-9AM'
                             ELSE CASE WHEN datepart(hh, PrimaryDate) >= 9 AND datepart(hh, PrimaryDate) <= 18 
                                          THEN 'Between 9AM-6AM' 
                                          ELSE CASE WHEN datepart(hh, PrimaryDate) > 18 
                                                       THEN 'Post-6PM' 
                                                       ELSE '' 
                                               END
                                  END 
                     END
```

The output should be:

```
TimeCalculation Count
---------------------
Pre-9AM           10
Between 9AM-6AM  583
Post-6PM           0
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No need to nest the case expressions. One single case is enough.

Answer (score 3):

First of all there is no need for nested `CASE`

```
update [document]
SET CalculatedTime = 
       case when DATEPART(hh,PrimaryDate) < 9 then 'Pre-9AM'
            when datepart(hh,PrimaryDate) >= 9 
                 AND datepart(hh,PrimaryDate) <= 18 then 'Between 9AM-6AM' 
            when datepart(hh,PrimaryDate) > 18 then 'Post-6PM' 
            else '' 
       end ;
```

Second if you want count per each case you could use:

```
SELECT CalculatedTime, COUNT(*)
FROM [document]
GROUP BY CalculatedTime;
```

It will work because you update entire table.

---

Using `MERGE`:

```
SELECT CalculatedTime, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
MERGE [document] trg
USING (SELECT 1 AS c) src
  ON trg.id = trg.id
WHEN MACHED THEN
   UPDATE SET CalculatedTime = 
       case when DATEPART(hh,PrimaryDate) < 9 then 'Pre-9AM'
            when datepart(hh,PrimaryDate) >= 9 
                 AND datepart(hh,PrimaryDate) <= 18 then 'Between 9AM-6AM' 
            when datepart(hh,PrimaryDate) > 18 then 'Post-6PM' 
            else '' 
       end
OUTPUT $action, inserted.CalculatedTime
) s(action, CalculatedTime)
WHERE action = 'UPDATE'
GROUP BY CalculatedTime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UPDATE OUTPUT into a table.

```
Declare @document table (CalculatedTime varchar(50));

    UPDATE [document]
        SET CalculatedTime = 
               Case when DATEPART(hh,PrimaryDate) < 9 then 'Pre-9AM'
                    when datepart(hh,PrimaryDate) >= 9 
                         AND datepart(hh,PrimaryDate) <= 18 then 'Between 9AM-6AM' 
                    when datepart(hh,PrimaryDate) > 18 then 'Post-6PM' 
                    else '' 
               End 
            OUTPUT INSERTED.CalculatedTime INTO @document

    SELECT CalculatedTime as TimeCalculation, COUNT(*) as Count
        FROM @document
            GROUP BY CalculatedTime;
```